# Parsing json using linux command line

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix

i have an json data :

```
{
   "error":false,
   "errorCode":0,
   "errorMsg":null,
   "data":{
      "geolocation":{
         "as":"AS201999 Fanavari Serverpars Argham Gostar Company Ltd.",
         "city":"Tehran"
      },
      "resolutions":[
         {
            "last_resolved":"2019-11-28 20:21:40",
            "hostname":"0663.ir"
         },
         {
            "last_resolved":"2019-12-15 11:38:17",
            "hostname":"12.ismconf.com"
         },
         {
            "last_resolved":"2019-12-04 22:36:09",
            "hostname":"1honey.ir"
         },
         {
            "last_resolved":"2019-12-04 21:19:59",
            "hostname":"irancdkey.ir"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

i want to get *hostname* value by executing commands :

```
cat ~/Downloads/data.json | json data.resolutions[].hostname
```

then i get an error, how to fix it and get hostname value like irancdkey.ir ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [jq](/questions/tagged/jq);

```
jq '.data.resolutions[].hostname' ~/Downloads/data.json
```

---

If your system does not have jq installed, try `apt-get install jq` for the most common systems.

Comment: is it not possible to use json?

Comment: @MuhamadFaizAzhar I'm not aware of any command line tool named 'json'. Jq is in my understanding the most used command line json handler

Comment: If you send us a link to `json`, we will take a look